# How to fetch conditional data from controller in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, datatables, laravel-8

I have two tables "users" and "predictions", the users table there are two columns "Org1" and "Org2" and the same columns are available in the predictions table "CurrOg1" and "CurrOrg2". When a user is registering he has to select "Org1" and "Org2" from dropdown and selected values are assigned to the user. Now I want to check the "Org1" and "Org2" value from users table with predictions table for the current user who login to app. For example, If user "Org1" is stored as "abc" while registering he must able to view data only where "CurrOrg" is "abc", Similarly for "Org2".
When I am trying to fetch results datatable error appears.

Here is my Register Controller and View Code:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'Org1' => [ 'string'],
            'Org2' => ['string'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'Org1' => $data['Org1'],
            'Org2' => $data['Org2'],
        ]);
        Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new WelcomeMail($user));

        return $user;
    }

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $Org1_list = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg1')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg1')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg1', 'ASC')
                            ->get();
        $Org2_list = DB::table('predictions')
                            ->select('CurrOrg2')
                            ->groupBy('CurrOrg2')
                            ->orderBy('CurrOrg2', 'ASC')
                            ->get();

        return view('auth.register', compact('Org1_list','Org2_list'));
    }
}
```

Register View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Org1" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Org1</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control" name="Org1" id="Org1">
                                    <option value="">Select Org1</option>
                                    @foreach($Org1_list as $use)
                                    @if(!empty($use))
                                    <option value="{{$use->CurrOrg1}}">{{$use->CurrOrg1}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('Org1')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Org2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Org2</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="form-control" name="Org2" id="Org2">
                                    <option value="">Select Org2</option>
                                    @foreach($Org2_list as $use)
                                    @if(!empty($use))
                                    <option value="{{$use->CurrOrg2}}">{{$use->CurrOrg2}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('Org2')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

This is my Predictions Controller:

```
{
                $user=DB:: table('users')
                      ->select('id','Org1','Org2','email')
                      ->get();

                if($CurrOrg1 == $user->Org1 && Auth::user()->email == $user->email)
                { 

                        $data = DB:: table('predictions')
                        ->select('id','EmployeeNumber','Role','Region','CurrOrg1','CurrOrg2','RiskZone','Probablity','Rating','Feedback','Gender','CurrOrg3','CurrOrg4','CurrOrg5','ProfessionalClassification','Local_Expat','EmployeeRoleSeniority','FeedRisklevel','Feedinfluencers','Action','Fname','Lname','Avgweekhr')
                        ->get();
                }
            }
            return datatables()->of($data)
            ->addColumn('Feedback', function($data)
            {   
                if($data->Action == 'No')
                {
                return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#CA0088;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                }
                else
                   {
                     return "<a href='#' style='background-color:#00A300;color:#fff' class='btn btn-sm Feedback' id='".$data->id."'>Feedback</a>";
                   } 
            })
            ->escapeColumns([])
            ->make(true);
        }
```

This is my view how I am loading Data:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fill_datatable();

    function fill_datatable(BusinessUnit = '', CurrOrg1 = '', CurrOrg2 = '', Role = '', Region = '' , Gender = '', CurrOrg3 = '' , CurrOrg4 = '', CurrOrg5 = '', ProfessionalClassification = '')
    {
        var dataTable = $('#members_data').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['excel'],
            processing: true,
            serverSide: false,
            

            ajax:{
                url: "{{ route('Predictions.index') }}",
                data:{BusinessUnit:BusinessUnit,CurrOrg1:CurrOrg1,CurrOrg2:CurrOrg2,Role:Role,Region:Region,Gender:Gender,ProfessionalClassification:ProfessionalClassification,CurrOrg3:CurrOrg3,CurrOrg4:CurrOrg4,CurrOrg5:CurrOrg5}
            },
            
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'EmployeeNumber',
                        name: 'EmployeeNumber',
                    render:function(data, type, row){
                    //console.log(row)}
                    //return "a"}
                    return "<a href='/detail/"+ row.id +"'>" + row.EmployeeNumber+"</a>"}
                },
                {
                    data:'Fname',
                    name:'Fname'
                },
                {
                    data:'Lname',
                    name:'Lname'
                },
                {
                    data:'Role',
                    name:'Role'
                },
                {
                    data:'Region',
                    name:'Region'
                },
                {
                    data:'CurrOrg1',
                    name:'CurrOrg1'
                },
                {
                    data:'CurrOrg2',
                    name:'CurrOrg2'
                },
});
```

Can someone suggest me What I am doing wrong here, or how I can achieve the solution for above problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show the error from the datatables?

Comment: @Tayyabmehar This is the error: DataTables warning: table id=members_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: have you debug your data from controller? what format of data you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the  get() function with first() to match conditions.

```
  $user=DB:: table('users')
                  ->select('id','Org1','Org2','email')
                  ->first();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working..same databale error

Comment: Have you checked the format of data you are taking from the controller is fine & what is desirable?

Comment: debug($data) before returning to it. Secondly make " serverSide: true" in ajax call.

Comment: Yes made the changes as you mentioned...and I am getting the data in desired format

Comment: I want to show user those records only where Org1=CurrOrg1 rest of the data should not be displayed..if Org1 values are"abc","xyx","mnc" then check the records in predictions table and show only records where CurrOrg1 is "abc","xyx","mnc" respectively

Comment: Do I need to use some join conditions to check?

Comment: You have to solve first problem by view data you are fetching in the controller to check conditions. Than go for ajax error. For debugging error in the ajax. Open network in the console & press OK from datatable error.  The error will be visible in the preview tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235681/discussion-between-tayyab-mehar-and-prashant).